# Prove that $\frac{1}{a^3(b+c)}+\frac{1}{b^3(a+c)}+\frac{1}{c^3(a+b)}\ge \frac32$

Tags: inequality, self-learning

> $a,b,c$ are positive reals with $abc = 1$. Prove that 
>   $$\frac{1}{a^3(b+c)}+\frac{1}{b^3(a+c)}+\frac{1}{c^3(a+b)}\ge \frac32$$

I try to use AM $\ge$ HM.

$$\frac{\dfrac{1}{a^3(b+c)}+\dfrac{1}{b^3(a+c)}+\dfrac{1}{c^3(a+b)}}3\ge \frac{3}{a^3(b+c)+b^3(a+c)+c^3(a+b)}$$
Then how I proceed.

Comment: Unfortunately, the inequality you used is pretty weak to solve this. As a start you may write each $a^3$ as $\frac{a}{b^2c^2}$

Comment: @Sayan: since $abc=1$ that is why you using $a^3=\frac{a}{b^2c^2}$. So, I need to replace $b^3,c^3$ with similar expression.

Comment: The motivation of this substitution is that, after this substitution every thing can be written in terms of $ab, bc, ca$. Isn't it? Now there is no harm in replacing $ab=x, bc=y, ca=z$, you still have $xyz=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Let $x=a^{-1},y=b^{-1},z=c^{-1}$. Rewrite $a^3=\dfrac{a^2}{bc}$, the inequality becomes
$$\frac{x^2}{y+z}+\frac{y^2}{z+x}+\frac{z^2}{x+y}\ge\frac32,$$
where $xyz=1$. That should be easy by Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: How will you use the Cauchy-Schwarz? Do you mean the AM-GM inequality perhaps?

Comment: @ypercube $((y+z)+(z+x)+(x+y))\left(\frac{x^2}{y+z}+\frac{y^2}{z+x}+\frac{z^2}{x+y}\right) \ge_{C.S.} (x+y+z)^2 \ge_{Am-Gm} 3(x+y+z)$

Answer (score 2):

As above write $x=a^{-1}$, $y=b^{-1}$, $c=z^{-1}$, so we are required to prove
$$ \frac{x^2}{y+z} + \frac{y^2}{z+x} + \frac{z^2}{x+y} \ge \frac{3}{2}, \qquad xyz=1.$$

Consider now that $\frac{x}{y+z}$, $\frac{y}{z+x}$, $\frac{z}{x+y}$ are in the same order as $x,y,z$. Then by the Rearrangement Inequality

$$ \frac{x^2}{y+z} + \frac{y^2}{z+x} + \frac{z^2}{x+y} \ge \frac{xy}{y+z} + \frac{yz}{z+x} + \frac{zx}{x+y} $$

and also

$$ \frac{x^2}{y+z} + \frac{y^2}{z+x} + \frac{z^2}{x+y} \ge \frac{xz}{y+z} + \frac{yz}{z+x} + \frac{zy}{x+y}; $$

averaging the two, we get

$$ \frac{x^2}{y+z} + \frac{y^2}{z+x} + \frac{z^2}{x+y} \ge \frac{x+y+z}{2} \ge \frac{3}{2}$$

the last step forllowing from AM-GM.

Answer (score 0):

$$ AM \ge GM $$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{a_{3}(b+c)} + \frac{1}{b_{3}(a+c)} + \frac{1}{c_{3}(a+b)}}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}}$$

$$  \frac{1}{a_{3}(b+c)} + \frac{1}{b_{3}(a+c)} + \frac{1}{c_{3}(a+b)} \ge \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2abc+ab^2 + ba^2 + ac^2 + ca^2 + bc^2 + cb^2}}$$

$$AM \ge GM $$
$$  \frac{2abc+ab^2 + ba^2 + ac^2 + ca^2 + bc^2 + cb^2}{8} \ge \sqrt[8]{a^8b^8c^8}$$

$$ \ge \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{8\sqrt[8]{a^8b^8c^8}}}$$

$$ \ge \frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{8}}$$

$$ \ge \frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: I don't think this is right. Your second use of AM-GM provides an *upper* bound for $\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{2abc+ etc}}$