# Prove that for $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^+$ with $abc = 1$, $\frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \ge \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

I would like confirmation that I did this proof correctly. If I did, it would be a milestone in my mathematical journey as it would be my first IMO problem.

By Cauchy, we have that $$\left( \frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \right) ( (b + c) + (a + c) + (a + b) ) \ge \left( \frac{1}{a^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{b^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{c^{3/2}} \right)^2.$$

By AM-GM, we have that $$\frac{1}{a^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{b^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{c^{3/2}} \ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{a^{3/2}b^{3/2}c^{3/2}}} = 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(abc)^{3/2}}} = 3.$$

Then, again by AM-GM, we have that $a + b + c \ge 3\sqrt[3]{abc} = 3$, and so $(b + c) + (a + c) + (a + b) = 2(a + b + c) \ge 2\cdot3 = 6.$

Thus, we have that $$\left( \frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \right) ( (b + c) + (a + c) + (a + b) ) \ge \left( \frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \right)6 \ge 3^2 = 9,$$ and so $$\frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \ge \frac 96 = \frac 32,$$ and we are done.

Comment: Your proof is correct and good solution of the problem.

Comment: Seems pretty fine...

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks @DeBARtha

Comment: Wait... this is not correct! It is correct that $a+b+c\ge 3$ and $\frac{1}{a^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{b^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{c^{3/2}} \ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{a^{3/2}b^{3/2}c^{3/2}}} = 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{(abc)^{3/2}}} = 3$. But, this DOES NOT IMPLY $\left( \frac{1}{a^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{b^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{c^{3/2}} \right)^2/2(a+b+c)\ge 3^2/(2\times 3)=3/2$ since you are DIVIDING $(a+b+c)$, which is at LEAST $3$, actually, you have $\left( \frac{1}{a^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{b^{3/2}} + \frac{1}{c^{3/2}} \right)^2/2(a+b+c)\ge 3^2/(2(a+b+c))\le3/2$ WHERE THE SIGN IS INVERTED!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\frac{1}{a^3(b+c)}+\frac{1}{b^3(a+c)}+\frac{1}{c^3(a+b)}\ge \frac32$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009022/prove-that-frac1a3bc-frac1b3ac-frac1c3ab-ge-frac32)? Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Ba%5E3(b%20%2B%20c)%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bb%5E3(a%20%2B%20c)%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bc%5E3(a%20%2B%20b)%7D%20%5Cge%20%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: @politeproofs You have $AB \ge 9$ and $B \ge 6$ and $AB \ge 6A$. How do you exclude the case $AB \ge 9 \ge 6A$? (Imagine: $1 \times 10 \ge 9$, $10 \ge 6$, $1\times 10 \ge 6 \times 1$. But $9 > 6\times 1$.)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is incorrect (see my comment.)

One solution is indeed by Cauchy Schwartz:

$$\left( \frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \right) ( a(b + c) + b(a + c) + c(a + b) )\ge(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c})^2=\frac{(ab+bc+ca)^2}{(abc)^2}=(ab+bc+ca)^2$$

Thus, we have

$$\left( \frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \right)\ge \frac{(ab+bc+ca)^2}{ ( a(b + c) + b(a + c) + c(a + b) )}=\frac{(ab+bc+ca)^2}{2(ab+bc+ca)}=\frac{ab+bc+ca}{2}$$

Since $abc=1$ so $ab+bc+ca\ge3\sqrt[3]{ab\times bc\times ca}=3\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}=3$, and this can yield the result.

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree with your comment. Do you agree with the following inequality?
$\left( \frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \right) ( (b + c) + (a + c) + (a + b) ) \ge \left( \frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \right)6 \ge 3^2 = 9$

Comment: @politeproofs I don't agree! What you actually have is $ \left( \frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \right)\times6  \le \left( \frac{1}{a^3(b + c)} + \frac{1}{b^3(a + c)} + \frac{1}{c^3(a + b)} \right) ( (b + c) + (a + c) + (a + b) ) \ge (...)^2\ge 3^2 = 9$. That is what I mean for your inequality is reversed.

Comment: @politeproofs To be clearer, you want to prove that $A\ge 3/2$ and you have proved $AB\ge 9$, and $B\ge 6$.  You CAN NOT do (and this is WHAT EXACTLY what you have done in your proof) $AB\ge 6A\ge 9$ since this expression you USED the fact that $A\ge 3/2$ (this is what you need to prove!) and $B\ge 9$. Also, you can't do $A=AB/B\ge 9/6=3/2$ since you are DIVIDING A LARGER VALUE! Also, giving an example to see why this false: if $A=1$ and $B=9$, it has $AB\ge 9$ and $B\ge 6$. but this does not imply $A\ge 3/2$.

Comment: I agree with this: I proved that $AB \ge 9$ and that $B \ge 6$. I do not understand why this does not imply $AB \ge 6A$?

Comment: @politeproofs This implies $AB\ge 6A$, but NOT $6A\ge 9$. Again, please think about the logic of this problem: you are going to PROVE that $A\ge 1.5$, you CAN NOT USE $A\ge 1.5$ to derive $6A\ge 9$.

Comment: @politeproofs Let $A=1, B=10$. Then $AB>9, B>6$ are both true, but $A \not \gt \frac32$. I hope you can figure out why you cannot make such a conclusion.